# Export Gridview data fetch by mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

hi i exported gridview data into excel but unfortunately the data inside the exported file was different,supposed to be a datatable.

[image]

Below is my script in export button, can you tell me what is wrong in my script. I am new in ASP.net thanks

```
try
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    excel.Visible = true;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
    int StartCol = 1;
    int StartRow = 1;
    int j = 0, i = 0;

    //Write Headers
    for (j = 0; j < GridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range myRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)sheet1.Cells[StartRow, StartCol + j];
        myRange.Value = GridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText;
    }

    StartRow++;

     //Write datagridview content
     for (i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
     {
         for (j = 0; j < GridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
         {
             try
             {
                 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range myRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)sheet1.Cells[StartRow + i, StartCol + j];
                 myRange.Value2 = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text + ";" == null ? "" : GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text + ";";

             }
             catch
             {
                 GridView1.DataBind();
             }
         }
     }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

     // ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(),
     //  "alertMessage",
     //   "alert(ex.ToString());", true);

}
```

Comment: Why are you binding the gridview in catch statement `GridView1.DataBind();`? Is that the only place or you have done it before starting this code block also i.e. before starting the excel export? Is the data being displayed in Gridview properly? Did you try to debug and check if there is data in gridview before exporting it to Excel?

Comment: I suspect that your `GridView` doesn't binding any cell. try to debug and check if data is properly binding into `GridView` or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi this is were i came up after long journey, i used the Aspose method on  Exporting Gridview in Excel, it's simple yet so powerfull! hope this will help,

Code behind Export_button:

```
  //Instantiate a new workbook
            Aspose.Cells.Workbook workbook = new Aspose.Cells.Workbook();
            //Get the first worksheet in the workbook
            Aspose.Cells.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
            //Import data from GridView control to fill the worksheet
            worksheet.Cells.ImportGridView(GridView1, 0, 0, new Aspose.Cells.ImportTableOptions() { IsFieldNameShown = true });
            worksheet.AutoFitColumns();
            //Send result to client in XLS format
            workbook.Save(this.Response, "export.xls", ContentDisposition.Attachment, new Aspose.Cells.XlsSaveOptions());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can export datagridview data to an excel using the below method:

```
public void ExportToExcel(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        try
        {
            dgv.SelectAll();
            dgv.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableAlwaysIncludeHeaderText;
            DataObject doj = dgv.GetClipboardContent();
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(doj);

            dgv.ClearSelection();

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application exap = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            exap.Visible = true;

            Workbook exwb = (Workbook)exap.Workbooks.Add();
            Worksheet exws = (Worksheet)exwb.Sheets["Sheet1"];

            exws.Paste();

            Clipboard.Clear();

            Range cell1 = exws.Cells[1, 2];
            Range cell2 = exws.Cells[dgv.Rows.Count + 1, dgv.ColumnCount + 1];
            Range cell3 = exws.Cells[1, dgv.ColumnCount + 1];

            Range range = exws.get_Range(cell1, cell2);
            Range colorrange = exws.get_Range(cell1, cell3);

            range.Borders.Weight = XlBorderWeight.xlThin;
            colorrange.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.SteelBlue;
            colorrange.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.White;

            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfd.Filter = "Excel File 2010 (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|Excel File 2003 (*.xls)|*.xls";

            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                exwb.SaveAs(sfd.FileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            }

        }

        catch(System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

This method copies all data in the datagridview & pastes it in an excel.You ofcourse need to add a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.

Alternately if you wish to export a datatable to excel you can try below method:

```
public void ExporttoExcel(System.Data.DataTable dtbl)
    {
        StringBuilder Output = new StringBuilder();

        //The first "line" will be the Headers.
        for (int i = 0; i < dtbl.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            Output.Append(dtbl.Columns[i].ColumnName + "\t");
        }

        Output.Append("\n");

        //Generate Cell Value Data
        foreach (DataRow Row in dtbl.Rows)
        {
            if (Row.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Row.ItemArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    //Handling the last cell of the line.
                    if (i == (Row.ItemArray.Length - 1))
                    {

                        Output.Append(Row.ItemArray[i].ToString() + "\n");
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        Output.Append(Row.ItemArray[i].ToString() + "\t");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Clipboard.SetText(Output.ToString());

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application exap = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        exap.Visible = true;

        Workbook exwb = (Workbook)exap.Workbooks.Add();
        Worksheet exws = (Worksheet)exwb.Sheets["Sheet1"];


        exws.Paste();

        Clipboard.Clear();

        Range cell1 = exws.Cells[1, 1];
        Range cell2 = exws.Cells[dtbl.Rows.Count, dtbl.Columns.Count];
        Range cell3 = exws.Cells[1, dtbl.Columns.Count];

        Range range = exws.get_Range(cell1, cell2);
        Range colorrange = exws.get_Range(cell1, cell3);

        range.Borders.Weight = XlBorderWeight.xlThin;
        colorrange.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.SteelBlue;
        colorrange.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.White;

        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();

        sfd.Filter = "Excel File 2010 (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|Excel File 2003 (*.xls)|*.xls";

        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            exwb.SaveAs(sfd.FileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        }


    }
```

Please check if these methods help.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, is it ok if i put this code into private void? or should i edit the private and make it public?

Comment: Yes you can make the method private but you use the method in the same class where you want to export. It will work

Comment: You mean just put the code on my "Export Button"? sorry i am new in ASP..

Comment: something like this

`private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e){ExportToExcel(datagridview1)}`

Comment: In your export button onclick event you call the ExportToExcel method like above

Comment: Please check if you are adding a  reference to the namespace System.Text

Answer (score 0):

use `Text.Replace("&nbsp;", "")`

```
 myRange.Value2 = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", "") + ";" == null ? "" : GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text + ";";
```

in markup

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeName" HeaderText="Name" NullDisplayText=" "/>
```

Comment: @Seryu use NullDisplayText=" " in Markup

Comment: sorry i am new in Asp, but i think my gridview is Templatefield cause i  generated various tables here.. if so, where should i put that in markup?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your GridView Bind fails. Below is the method which you can try.

```
private void ExportToExcel()
{
    //First fetch all records from grid to dataset
    DataSet dset = new DataSet();
    dset.Tables.Add();
    //First Add Columns from gridview to excel
    for (int i = 0; i < gridView.Columns.Count; i++) //GridView is id of gridview
    {
        dset.Tables[0].Columns.Add(gridView.Columns[i].HeaderText);
    }
    //add rows to the table 
    System.Data.DataRow dr1;
    for (int i = 0; i < gridView.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        dr1 = dset.Tables[0].NewRow(); //For Example There are only 3 columns into gridview
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblCCName = 
          (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)gridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("lblCCName");
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblItemName = 
          (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)gridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("lblItemName");
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblItemCode = 
          (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)gridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("lblItemCode");
        dr1[0] = lblCCName.Text.ToString();
        dr1[1] = lblItemName.Text.ToString();
        dr1[2] = lblItemCode.Text.ToString(); 
        dset.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr1); 
    }
    //below code is export dset to excel
    ApplicationClass excel = new ApplicationClass();
    Workbook wBook;
    Worksheet wSheet; 
    wBook = excel.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
    wSheet = (Worksheet)wBook.ActiveSheet;
    System.Data.DataTable dt = dset.Tables[0];
    System.Data.DataColumn dc = new DataColumn();
    int colIndex = 0;
    int rowIndex = 4;
    foreach (DataColumn dcol in dt.Columns)
    {
        colIndex = colIndex + 1;
        excel.Cells[5, colIndex] = dcol.ColumnName;
    }
    foreach (DataRow drow in dt.Rows) 
    {
        rowIndex = rowIndex + 1;
        colIndex = 0;
        foreach (DataColumn dcol in dt.Columns)
        {
            colIndex = colIndex + 1;
            excel.Cells[rowIndex + 1, colIndex] = drow[dcol.ColumnName];
        }
    }
    wSheet.Columns.AutoFit();
    // Server File Path Where you want to save excel file.
    String strFileName = Server.MapPath("~\\Images\\StockStatement.xls");
    Boolean blnFileOpen = false;
    try
    {
        System.IO.FileStream fileTemp = File.OpenWrite(strFileName);
        fileTemp.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        blnFileOpen = false;
    }
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(strFileName))
    //It checks if file exists then it delete that file.
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(strFileName);
    }  
}
```

In the `Button_Click()` event, call this function.

Comment: hi got error in compiling around:

 ApplicationClass excel = new ApplicationClass(); 
    -Interop Type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClase' cannot be embended.

Comment: did you added all required namespaces? Also check reference it requires Microsoft.Office.Interop 12.0.

Comment: i'm sorry what namespaces should i add? yes i already add Microsoft.Office.Interop 12.0 on my reference..

Comment: 1) Add reference below in your project:

`Microsoft Office 12.0 Control Library`

Now, add NameSpace in your Page at which you want to use this functionality:

`using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;`

Comment: i already did that before i copy your code but still have errors.

Comment: ok. try with set `<identity impersonate="true"/>` in your web.config.