# Why Identifier Expected?

Tags: mysql, asp.net

hi can you please help me what is missing or problem with my script? i keep on getting compiling error: Identifier Expected. It is in the character ".[i"

```
myRange.Value2 = GridView1.[i,j].Value + ";" == null ? "" : GridView1.[i,j].Text + ";";
```

Comment: because it's supposed to be `GridView1[i,j]`

Comment: Just remove the point before the opening square brackets

Comment: if i remove the dot, this error show 
"Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It will be:**

```
myRange.Value2 = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text+ ";" == null ? "" : GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text + ";";
```

`GridView.Rows[i].Cells[j]`
where `i = row index` and
`j = cell index`

Comment: it gives me compile error:
'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: what is the error now after replacing `Value` to `Text`?

Comment: did u replaced `Value` to `Text`?? If Yes then you should not get same error .

Comment: yes it solves now my problem, but my other problem is in other topic could you please take a look if you could help me? here the link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959790/export-gridview-data-fetch-by-mysql/37960182?noredirect=1#comment63370276_37960182

Comment: will check it. Mark it Answer if this has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a typo: there is a dot after `GridView1`, which isn't allowed since it expects an identifier then (as the message says). `GridView1.Rows` would have been valid for example.

Another problem is that your logic is wrong.

This code will never yield `true`, since `";"` is not null:

```
GridView1[i, j].Value + ";" == null
```

I think you should drop the `+ ";"`.

Comment: it shows error in Gridview1[i, j] and Gridview1[i, j] 
"Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView'

Comment: Then your control doesn't have an indexer. Sure you didn't mean `GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text`?

Comment: how should i add indexer? i am new in ASP.

Comment: yes, i tried that before and i was not getting something, so i tried the format i used in C# that is running but i was getting compile error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959790/export-gridview-data-fetch-by-mysql/37960182?noredirect=1#comment63370276_37960182 

this is the link of my whole script, which i posted earlier..